# Must/Have to: observation or advice

Tags: sentence-meaning, modal-verbs

How can I understand if sentences as for example

> You have to/must be strong

are observation or advice?
Is it entirely up to the context?

Comment: We're told that on November 10, 1871 upon locating David Livingstone in Africa, Henry Morton Stanley said [*Dr. Livingstone, I presume?*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Livingstone,_I_presume) But he *could* just as well have said ***You must be Dr. Livingstone.*** Which in context would be a ***greeting***, not an observation or advice. In short, ***context is everything***.

Comment: *You have to be strong,* means "being strong is a requirement of external origin"; by contrast, *You must be strong,* (assuming we're not talking about a *conclusion* which FumbleFingers exemplifies above) is more about the speaker's requirement; i.e., the speaker is imposing this requirement themselves.

Comment: It is entirely up to the context, and without any context in the question, any other answer you may get is opinion-based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it entirely up to the context?

It is.  The sentence is ambiguous and can be either imperative or indicative.

In live speech, placing stress on *have* or *must* will make it more likely to be understood as a command.  Placing stress on *strong* will make it more likely to be understood as a statement.